# Запись и воспроизведение звука Си

Tags: c, gcc, драйвер

Как я без стороних библиотек, напрямую могу брать звук?
Я не знаю, но слышал что вроде бы для этого надо с драйвером микрофона пообщатся, и с его помощью записывать.
Уточню, нужно сделать на чисто си, без либ и тд...
Хотел бы услышать прав ли я на счет драйвера, и небольшое напутсвие.

Comment: Си не умеет записывать воспроизводить звук. Нужно использовать платформозависимые (например WinAPI) или платформо-независимые (QT) библиотеки. И это надо уточнять в ворпосе. Драйвер - тем более платформо-зависимое решение. Но, как правило напрямую в драйвер в 99% случаев не стучат, а делают это через клиентскую библиотеку ( т.е. dll/so).

Comment: Я подумал что Си при взаимодействие со звуковыми драйверами, может записывать и воспроизводить звук

Comment: Вы можете взять из библиотеки нужные куски, и добавить себе в код, тогда вам не приёдется подключать либы (имеется ввиду h). Но без подключения lib - врядли что-то получится, т.к. как минимум даже для ф-ции GetProcAddress (есть аналог и в линуксе) нужно подключать либу (lib или def, некоторые сборщики умеют через опции) которая прилинкует dll или so с этой функцией.

Comment: Голый си позволяет реализовать алгоритм. А взаимодействие идёт через библиотеки. Теоретически не используя библиотеки можно разве что или писать напрямую в видеопамять из под DOS, или вызывать API через инекцию используя там... ассемблерные `int xxh` или `call xxxx` (но затраты по времени на такое не оправдывают отказ от библиотек)

Comment: Драйвер - это прослойка между функциями ОС и железом. А прикладные программы взаимодействуют с функциями ОС, которые предоставляют единый интерфейс ко всем драйверам данного типа. По этой причине вам в любом случае надо смотреть как работать со звуком в вашей операционной системе. Так что мне только остается присоединиться к комментариям выше: или берите платформо-независимую библиотеку (которая под каждой ОС ведет работу со звуком так, как в ней принято), Или используйте функционал ядра ОС/ее библиотек для прямого доступа. А для этого надо как минимум точно в вопросе указать ОС

Comment: Замечу, что под linux/unix все сведется к работе с "обычным" файлом устройства, возможно с небольшими дополнениями в виде специализированных ioctl. Под Windows это будет обращение к функциям WinAPI из библиотек ядра ОС (они не "сторонние", они в комплекте с ядром ОС идут и без них к ядру в принципе не обратиться)